# 301 redirect and /index.php

Tags: redirect, seo

i made a grave mistake with my site. i didn't check the difference between .www and non .www so the one that had the www in it was a little broken.

well anyways i've plugged a 301 redirect in here, and for http://mysite.com it's fine as usual, but the http://www.mysite.com now adds on /index.php. that can't be the best for SEO, right? (the cms is Textpattern if that is relevant)

another problem this redirect code has is: http://www.mysite.com/blog will take you back to the homepage.

what do you think?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: 301 is for permanent redirect, therefore all your page ranks that were on your ancient domain are going to be ported over the new domain (Depends on the search engine, but I'm pretty positive that it's what happen with Google)

Comment: hmm this isn't really about old domain vs. new one. i'm just trying to prevent there being a www. version to my site and a non-www. version.

Comment: These are 2 different domain names and are counted as 2 different sites. From the point-of-view of your www domain, the non-www one is "the new domain".

Answer (score 0):

i seem to have found the problem. i think that 301 script has to be at the top of the .htaccess document or it will cause problems. such as the blog problem and the /index.php inconsistency.